# Tried all the solution but still can not fix error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, oracle11g, eclipse-photon

fail to ping oracle database from eclipse. I had tried to change the maximum processes number to 1000, and restart the database. Besides I had tried a lot of solutions from Google but all does not work. Event reinstall eclipse and my oracle database also can not solve it. Anyone can help me figure out the solution please?

below shows the error details:

java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)

at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.oracle.JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.java:27)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)

at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
```

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

```
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:399)
```

Comment: please share your connection string, did you try using
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle.hostserver2.mydomain.ca:1522/ABCD (for service)
or
jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.hostserver1.mydomain.ca:1521:XYZ (for SID)
format?

Comment: Are you able to connect to that database with other tools (sqlplus, SQL Developer, simple Java JDBC application)? According to this question it may happen when you open too many database connections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230446/java-sql-sqlexception-listener-refused-the-connection-with-the-following-error

Comment: Here is my connection string :
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
I use SID format

Comment: yes, I can connect the database using sql, slqplus, and also can do the tnsping

Comment: Why are you running shared server on a local XE database?

Comment: it runs automatically, does it makes this error occurred?